# deepEqual() Method Explanation

Tags: javascript

I'm supposed to write a function that returns the below structure, given a number as height. For example, this is the expected output for 5 as input parameter:

```
["    #",
 "   ##",
 "  ###",
 " ####",
 "#####"]
```

I wrote the below code, which visually appears to attend the criteria, but is throwing the **expected [ Array(5) ] to deeply equal [ Array(5) ]** error.

```js
function escada(andares) {
  let minhaEscada = []
  for (let andarAtual = 1; andarAtual <= andares; andarAtual++) {
    let degrau = ''
    for (let pecaAtual = 1; pecaAtual <= andares; pecaAtual++) {      
      if (pecaAtual<andarAtual){
        degrau += '\xa0'
      } else {
        degrau += '#'
      }
    }
    minhaEscada.unshift(degrau)
  }
  return minhaEscada
}

console.log(escada(5));
```

What does it mean? Why the output of my code is not considered equal as the requested?

Comment: What is `\xa0` for? Shouldn't it be a simple space character?

Comment: Your code seems to work and I do not get an error.